# clearTimeout not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, timeout

I have written a simple function that sends request to the server after certain time interval.

```js
var initialTimer;

$('.cart').on('keyup change', 'input', function () {

        if (initialTimer) {
            clearTimeout(initialTimer);
        }

        initialTimer = setTimeout(function () {
           $.ajax({
                    url: "https://httpbin.org/get",
                    type: 'GET',
                }).done(function (response) {
                    alert(response.url);
                }).fail(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }).always(function () {
                    console.log('request ended.');
                });
        }, 500);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cart">
  <input type="number" name="quantity">
</div>
```

This code works fine with `Firefox` but not working in `Chrome`. It does not work in `Chrome` while incrementing/decrementing using the input box but works if I type the number inside input box.

Comment: Chances are you forgot to call updateCart() to initialize the event listener

Comment: @JohnSmith so why it's working on Firefox ?

Comment: @LalitThapa could you provide the HTML please ?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show your HTML but this code works for me in chrome:

```
var initialTimer;
$('.cart').on('keyup', function () {

    if (initialTimer) {
        clearTimeout(initialTimer);
    }

    initialTimer = setTimeout(function () {
       console.log('test');
       // Send AJAX request to server
    }, 1000);

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dcjh47fs/

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the jQuery signature is incorrect. Try this instead:

```
$('.cart').on('keyup', function () {
    ...
});
```